Engaging students in the beauty of mathematics
I am a teaching assistant for Calculus I, and as a TA, I also take on teaching responsibilities.
My goal as a teaching assistant is to help students appreciate the beauty of mathematics—not just processing theorems or mechanically learning definitions and proofs.
Currently, we are working on the topic of infimums and supremums. I want to show students why we need to equip R with a structure such as a "complete ordered field," the very reason why the real numbers are unique. From this, I hope to connect topics like the fact that without completeness, there would be no concept of continuity. I also want to introduce the idea that infinities come in different sizes and emphasize the importance of the supremum axiom.
I would love to present interesting examples and give a lecture that brings all these ideas together in a way that's accessible and exciting.
I'd really appreciate any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this and make a Calculus class the Calculus class.
Ideas, contributions, and additional topics for the lecture are very welcome!

This question is similar to: How do I show students the Beauty of Mathematics?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Calculus 1 is taken by many people across the broad swathes of STEM. Most of them don't care about the "Beauty of Mathematics" - they will use calculus as a required tool, that is all.

Please don't teach calculus students about complete ordered fields, unless it's an honors course. You'll instantly lose them. If they continue into Linear Algebra, they (might) learn it then. Remember that many of them can't even reliably compute logarithms. The first complicated notion in an introductory calculus class is a limit - spend lots of time there and help your students understand how limits and continuity relate to each other.

"From this, I hope to connect topics like the fact that without completeness, there would be no concept of continuity." This is simply not true (one can for instance talk about continuous and discontinuous functions on the rationals), so I recommend that you do not teach this to your students.

Can you which tomes by which authors you'd most recommend, and what they leave unsaid? How, for instance, might your approach differ from Steven Strogatz' in Infinite Powers?
For what my view is worth, I suspect the Question in Daniel R. Collins' link is on a very different level, even if the two share basic aims.

All I can tell in this respect is one personal story and one moral.
Personal story:
Time and place:
7th grade, city math olympiad, some problem in which the key idea was that if a quadratic polynomial can be both positive and negative on the real line, then it has real zeroes.
Me: so $p(x)<0$ at $a$ and $p(x)>0$ at $b$. Since $p$ is a continuous function, we conclude that its graph must cross the real line.
Eximiner: What is a continuous function?
Me: a function whose graph is a continuous curve.
Examiner: What is a continuous curve?
Me: A curve without jumps.
Examiner: What is a jump?
Me: The place where the curve breaks.
Examiner: What is a break in the curve?
Me: Isn't that clear?
Examiner: No.
Me: OK, let me think more then...
Going back to the place, figuring out some ugly algebra nonsense with fractions and quadratic roots, checking that the expression under the quadratic root is positive as a sum of squares and positive numbers, trying again with this monster and the same examiner, passing, but very dissatisfied.
Some years later:
1st university year, second lecture in analysis, the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a continuous function.
Me: Wow, so simple and elegant and also completely formal! But how does it imply what I tried to say many years ago?
Fourth lecture in analysis, the IVT proof.
$f(a)<0, f(b)>0$. Consider $A=\{x\in[a,b]:f<0 \text{ on }[a,x]$. Put $c=\sup A$. Then $f(c)=0$. (with a few more details, of course).
Me: Great! Now, of course, we postulated the existence of $\sup$ as the "completeness axiom" of $\mathbb R$, but can we derive it from something even more basic?
Going home, finding a book on the construction of $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$ (Dedekind cuts), satisfied at that point.
Now the
Moral:
You cannot possibly impress anyone by answering a question he/she has never asked or has been forced to ask. Conversely, an elegant answer to an old problem someone has been struggling with for a long time invariably results in a "Wow".
All conclusions from this small piece of writing are left to the reader to draw. The task of classifying it as "useful", "missing the point", "non-answer", "rant" or anything else is delegated to moderators.
Just my two cents, as usual...

"ou cannot possibly impress anyone by answering a question he/she has never asked or has been forced to ask. " On the topic of dedekind cuts, the question that students have maybe already asked would be, "Does 0.999... = 1 ?"

@Brian: I see that as a question about the decimal representation of rational numbers. How is it related to Dedekind cuts?

@MartinArgerami You can of course find the limit of (0.9, 0.99, ...) just staying within rational numbers, so I agree it's not the best example. But there is a connection between decimal representations and Dedekind cuts: Let $A$ be the set of rationals that are smaller than any partial decimal representation, and let $B = \mathbb{Q}\setminus A$. Now we can show that $(A,B)$ is a Dedekind cut, and we could define that the Dedekind cut is what the decimal representation means. We can go on to show that the Dedekind cuts we get from $0.999...$ and $1.000...$ are the same.

Essentially, people who intuitively think that $0.999... < 1$ probably think of $0.999...$ as some kind of a number that is smaller than $1$ but infinitesimally (without using this word) close to it. Constructing reals formally allows us to understand that such a thing doesn't exist in reals.

I would caution you against being too ambitious in this direction. The first step to making someone appreciate the beauty of math is to get them to say "huh, that's kind of cool." If you get students to say that, you are already doing very well.
There's a danger in making your presentation too high-flying, which is that students will struggle to understand what you're saying. I've seen it happen many times. The exact thing that excites you about this circle of ideas--the inter-connection of several different concepts--is what makes it hard for students to follow, when most of the concepts are new to them. For example, if you want students to understand different sizes of infinity on anything more than a fact-regurgitation level, you probably need to devote one or two entire lectures to this, and have them solve exercises about it. In other words, make it a full-fledged topic on the syllabus, which I'm guessing as the TA is not your decision to make. Bringing it up along the way as you explain something else will only lead to confusion.
Having said that, making the material engaging and interesting is a worthwhile goal, of course. I would just be careful not to make your lectures more difficult in pursuit of that. Try to find interesting nuggets that are a little more down-to-earth, while understanding that many students are coming from a place of anxiety and want you to help them be successful in the course (this is not mutually exclusive with liking or being interested in the material). Presenting a taste or preview of more advanced stuff can be a nice thing to do when it comes up naturally, but a little of this goes a long way.

"Struggle to understand what you are saying" could even be fine, as long as it isn't "why all this nonsense?".

My experience is that you want to drop these sorts of things in as almost asides. For your specific example, something like:
The fundamentally important thing about $\mathbb{R}$ is that it is connected -- it has no gaps. If you have already talked about sups and infs, point out that if you divide the real line in two sets $A$ and $B$ with each entry in $A$ less than each entry in $B$ then $A$ has a sup, $B$ has an inf, these two coincide and that value belongs to exactly one of $A$ or $B$. You can draw this on the board quickly, without formal definitions and statements.  Then, show that this is not the case for the integers or the rationals (they most likely "know" that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a fraction -- or at least they have been told so).
One advantage here is that you don't confuse them by students leaving thinking that "continuous" (at least as used in Calculus I) applies to $\mathbb{R}$ rather than functions.
For those that go on to Calculus II, they'll encounter this idea again with the monotone convergence theorem.
BUT, do not overwhelm them. I had a colleague in grad school who was TAing Calculus II at the same time we were all in a Real Analysis class that worked through Stieltjes integration. He then decide to teach $u$-substitution by explaining Stieltjes. This went poorly, unsurprisingly. (Also, as this answer explains nicely, is not precisely correct.)
I hint at the beauty -- and call it out: "There is more going on here. Please come talk with me and/or take more math if you are interested." But I don't dwell on it and I make as clear as I can what things I expect them to be able to reproduce on assignments/exams and which things are just for fun.

If you want to get/keep students excited about the material, then what you should point out to them are the exciting things going on at the level of the course. Other answers point out the dangers of attempting to do this at too high of a level: losing their interest entirely. But if you think hard about what you must teach them, and if you think hard about the proper level to which your explanations should be pitched so as to enhance their understanding, you can find exciting things at that level itself.
There are interesting and beautiful mathematical patterns to be observed and emphasized in 1st semester calculus, and this is what you should aim for. I don't want to tell you what you should find interesting and beautiful enough to emphasize, because that's up to you. But look for anything that might be interesting or surprising or beautiful.
Here's one modest example. Students have been investing a lot into algebra when they enter a calculus course. I love the patterns of algebraic cancellation which occur in working out the limit proofs of derivative formulas, and that make the calculations work. I get excited about them, and I attempt to impart my excitement: another cool cancellation!!

This is an excellent answer, in that it advises OP on what to do to achieve their goal, not just (wisely) warning OP off of what not to do.

A note in passing.
Showing that rational numbers are not "enough" is easy: square roots. But then, is it enough to add all roots? No, right? But showing that adding all (real) algebraic numbers is not enough is not that easy. I don't know if going the countable vs uncountable route is beatiful or ugly...
(And continuity is treated in topology without needing completeness, so be careful there.)

I think the real beauty of mathematics lies in its practicality and utility; even the most abstract concepts are there because they make something easier and simpler, believe it or not: abstraction is a tool for simplifying our thinking. Take the natural numbers, for example - you can imagine that we started with collections of things, say I have potatoes, you have apples; I want some apples and you want potatoes. How do you figure out what would be a fair exchange? Perhaps we agree that if I give you a potato, then you give me an apple and so on, but at some point people figured out that collections where you could pair elements up side by side, were somehow the same size, and thus numbers were born. Maybe this is only a just so story, but I think it captures the spirit.
However, there is one example I don't think has been mentioned: the proof that a convex function is continuous: it illustrates very well how and why we use the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ construction, and it is wonderfully intuitive. It got a standing ovation, no less, the first time I saw it demonstrated. Look it up - there must be a youtube video or something.

I can't recommend anything specifically on the topic of infimums and supremums, but if it is calculus and linear algebra I can recommend looking into 3D graphics.
This is a very broad topic that may involve such topics as vector calculus, matrices, quaternions but you can carve out some part in order to demonstrate importance of working with functions.
One particular area that I'm personally very interested about is SDF or signed distance function (most often in computer graphics people use just distance functions, not signed distance functions) which is one of the key concepts in the procedural graphics.
Knowing how to creating a distance function to draw a certain shape, how to combine distance functions to create something interesting, creating patterns is not only intellectually pleasing but is quite useful practically in computer graphics, for example creating a wood texture, bricks-alike pattern etc. I personally find this topic extremely interesting as it is a blend of art, mathematics, computer science (although only a little).
As an illustration of what I'm talking about I'd recommend looking at

The Book of Shaders specifically "Algorithmic Drawing"
Examples of 2D SDFs
One example of practical applications of SDFs: visually pleasing font with antialiasing

As far as I know the math behind distance function approximations could be extremely complicated (for me) although to be honest I'm lacking mathematical education to be a judge of that, e.g. fast convolution-based methods for computing SDF and its derivatives.
If you're looking for a less complicated topic the same book of shaders also illustrates various coordinate systems, rotations, translations etc. which is also used in procedural graphics if you're looking for something less complex.
